# Radiobuttons (vertical) with extra form elements inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

using bootstrap, what is the right way to create a group of radio buttons (underneath each other) and have other form elements next to only some of the radio buttons?

Pseudo Layout:

```
<Radiobutton1> <Text_Radiobutton1>   <inputform-Text> <some Text>
<Radiobutton2> <Text_Radiobutton2>  
<Radiobutton3> <Text_Radiobutton3>  
<Radiobutton4> <Text_Radiobutton4>   <checkbox1> <Text_Checkbox1>
<Radiobutton5> <Text_Radiobutton5>
```

Thanks for any help,

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

The only thing you need to do is putting classes for the bootstrap but you can find that on w3schools or other websites.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label >
  <input name="radio" type="radio" >
  <span ></span>
  <span >Toggle this custom radio</span>
  <input type="text">
</label>
<br/>
<label class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input name="radio" type="radio">
  <span></span>
  <span>Or toggle this other custom radio</span>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="checkbox">
    <span >Toggle this checkbox</span>
</label>
```

Comment: From what the layout looks like, yes it is. Now, the two radiobuttons have to behave as one group, i.e. if i select either one, then the other one has to be unselected.

Comment: Now you can choose one radio at a time, you can do this by giving the radio a name="blabla". They both need to have the same name to have it work.

Comment: Thanks, looks great. So some follow up questions for my understanding: 1) How ist "custom-control" related to  "form-group" and "form-inline" which are explained in the bootstrap docs?

Comment: i forgot to take that out. Dont use that yet use form-group.

Comment: Great, i will try this at home

Comment: Assume, i would like to align the two text-input-boxes as well. What would your code look like? I.e., the upper text-input-box would have to be moved right a bit.

Comment: I need to go to work just look on the internet about columns in bootstrap. Watch a tutorial.

Comment: I tried around yesterday a lot. your inline example works great. But it seems when using the inline form you cannot control the position and width of the text input. So if you have a solution for above example where 1) the text inputs are left aligned and 2) the width of them are smaller,that would be perfect!